# SC_FIFO write : First chance exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, fifo, systemc

I've written a simple program which will send data from a 2D array from one module to another module, however it does not seem to work and I am not sure why. Here is my code:

Server.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

SC_MODULE(Server){
    sc_in <bool> clock;
    sc_fifo_out <sc_uint<20> > writePath;

    bool init_flag;
    int numRobots;

    void Server_Main();

    SC_CTOR(Server){
        init_flag = 0;
        numRobots = 4;
        SC_METHOD(Server_Main){ sensitive << clock.pos(); }
    }
};
```

Server.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Server.h"

void Server::Server_Main(){
    if (init_flag == 0){
        int robotPath[4][5] = {
            { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1 },
            { 2, 1, 6, 3, 4 },
            { 3, 2, 9, 5, 1 },
            { 4, 1, 6, 8, 7 }
        };

        //Write robot path to Sensor
        for (int i = 0; i < numRobots; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                cout << "SERVER MODULE: Write Robot Paths " << i << ": " << robotPath[i][j] << endl;
                writePath.write(robotPath[i][j]);
            }
        }
        init_flag = 1;
    }
    else{ sc_stop(); }
}
```

Sensor.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

SC_MODULE(Sensor){
    //sc_in <bool> clock;
    sc_fifo_in <sc_uint<20> > readPath;

    int robotPath[4][5]; 

    void loadPath();
    //void Sensor_Main();

    SC_CTOR(Sensor){
        //SC_METHOD(Sensor_Main){ sensitive << clock.pos(); }
        SC_THREAD(loadPath){}
    }
};
```

Sensor.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Sensor.h"

void Sensor::loadPath(){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (1){
        robotPath[i][j] = readPath.read();
        cout << "SENSOR MODULE: Read Robot " << i << " Path " << j << " : " << robotPath[i][j] << endl;
        if (j == 4){
            j = 0;  //Set index to beginning of array
            i++;    //Move to next robot
        }
        else{ j++; } //Continue loading path for current robot
    }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

#include "Sensor.h"
#include "Server.h"

using namespace std;

int sc_main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    sc_clock clock("sysclock", 50, SC_MS, .5);
    sc_fifo <sc_uint<20> > robotPath;

    Sensor sensor_mod("Sensor");
    sensor_mod.readPath(robotPath);

    Server server_mod("Server");
    server_mod.clock(clock);
    server_mod.writePath(robotPath);

    sc_start();

    return 0;
}
```

Here's what my output looks like:

[image]

Here's the error i get from VS2013:
[image]

The program seems to throw an exception when it tries to write `robotPath[3][1]` to the fifo but im not sure why. I specified my fifo size to be 20 so that it can store 20 values at once but I dont send more than 20 values and this exception is happening when i try to write the 17th value so maybe im misunderstanding the use of `sc_fifo_out`. It might be some obvious mistake im overlooking but im kind of burnt out at this point and cannot figure out what it is im messing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to model a Hardware design using SystemC or trying to use SystemC for software modelling?
It seems you have mixed up the contexts.

Here are a list of pointers you need to consider:

- In Server module Server_Main() should be registered as a SC_THREAD:

  ```
  SC_THREAD(Server_Main);
  sensitive << clk.pos();
  ```

  Since you are using sc_fifo's write method which internally calls wait(), in SystemC it is illegal to use wait in a SC_METHOD.
- Modify the Server.cpp as mentioned below:

  ```
  void Server::Server_Main() {
    int robotPath[4][5] = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 1 },
                           { 2, 1, 6, 3, 4 },
                           { 3, 2, 9, 5, 1 },
                           { 4, 1, 6, 8, 7 }};
    //Write robot path to Sensor
    for (int i = 0; i < numRobots; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        cout << "SERVER MODULE: Write Robot Paths " << i << ": " << robotPath[i][j] << endl;
        writePath.write(robotPath[i][j]);
        wait(); //< Notice this wait statement.
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Add a **wait()** statement in the while loop of the Sensor.cpp.
- Also **sc_fifo<  sc_uint<20> >** is not instantiating a **sc_fifo** with depth 20 as you might think.
  It is actually instantiating a **sc_fifo** with **sc_uint<20>** as the datatype which is used for modelling a 20-bit unsigned integer, and the default depth of fifo as 16 as per the SystemC specs.

  You can instantiate a **sc_fifo<>** with depth 20 as mentioned below:

  ```
  sc_fifo<sc_uint<20> > robotPath("robotPath", 20);
  ```

  **Note:** You don't need to do this since the above change from SC_METHOD to SC_THREAD and also updating the **Server_Main** will invalidate this behavior.

Comment: When you say that converting from SC_METHOD to SC_THREAD would invalidate the behavior, what do you mean? If i have one thread writing and another thread reading, but only to read once i've written 20 samples to the fifo, wouldnt i need this behavior?

Comment: @Javia1492 If you need to have this behavior that once the fifo is written with 20 samples and then trigger the execution of Sensor::loadPath() [thread], then you will have to look into static and dynamic sensitivity of the SystemC specifications.